# Compute HMAC_SHA256 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hash, frontend, sha256, hmac

I want to compute the SHA256 based HMAC for some `key` and a `message` in front-end using JavaScript. It's easily done in Python like so:

```py
import hmac
h = hmac.new(b'key', b'message', 'sha256')
print(h.hexdigest())
```

I searched and found something in NodeJS but can't do the same thing in front-end (I mean in browser of the user), which I guess I need to bundle the required library and do the stuff but could not figure out how.

Comment: Many of those libraries are usable in-browser as well.  If your question is about bundling, post a new separate question for that.  A quick tip... check out Browserify.  It does the bundling in the most painless way.  Webpack and a collection of modules for it is an alternative, but I've found Webpack to be the biggest pain.  Spent years messing with it and decided to abandon as it's such a hassle to work with, and it breaks regularly.

Comment: @Brad, I can edit the question if necessary, but will be glad if you post your answer.

Comment: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha256](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha256).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu my question is about using this kind of stuff in browser, could you post an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`npm i js-sha256` [[link]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha256)

will install it on the domain of your choice, in `node_modules/` and you can link it from there.

```js
console.log(sha256.hmac('key', 'message'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-sha256/0.9.0/sha256.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I guess I can download the library and serve it through my own site instead of `cdnjs.cloudflare.com`, right?

Comment: Yes, it's publicly available. You should install it with `npm` (`npm i js-sha256`), so you can upgrade it whenever a new version is released. `npm` installs it in your `node_packages` and you can link it from there. You have complete control over version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, *happy coding :)*